# Running grunt task with api, without command line

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I want to create and run grunt task in node.js code for test use.

```
var foo = function() {
    var grunt = require("grunt");

    var options = {"blahblah": null} // ...creating dynamic grunt options, such as concat and jshint
    grunt.initConfig(options);
    grunt.registerTask('default', [/*grunt subtasks*/]);
}
```

But this doesn't work. Grunt doesn't seem to run any task. I'm almost sure that there is some API to run grunt task externally without command line, but don't know how to do it.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can. I don't know why anyone would need to do this as currently Grunt is a *command line tool*. **WARNING: I don't recommend running Grunt in this way.** But here it is:

```
var grunt = require('grunt');

// hack to avoid loading a Gruntfile
// You can skip this and just use a Gruntfile instead
grunt.task.init = function() {};

// Init config
grunt.initConfig({
  jshint: {
    all: ['index.js']
  }
});

// Register your own tasks
grunt.registerTask('mytask', function() {
  grunt.log.write('Ran my task.');
});

// Load tasks from npm
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

// Finally run the tasks, with options and a callback when we're done
grunt.tasks(['mytask', 'jshint'], {}, function() {
  grunt.log.ok('Done running tasks.');
});
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I wanted to run Grunt dynamically to set up some web-based test environment. To achieve it, I needed to run Grunt in nodeJS code, or using exec()-like thing to make up CLI command of Grunt. I thought the former was more natural.

Comment: I usually use `grunt.util.spawn({ grunt: true, args: ['taskname'] }, function() {})` for testing that way. It spawns Grunt more closely to how a user would run Grunt.

Comment: I also needed this.
My particular use case, is to ensure that an application created by a generator builds correctly, as part of the generator's tests.

Comment: Programmatically running grunt is also useful when testing grunt plugins. You could, of course, use child_process.spawn, but many test coverage tools don't count (or sometimes even work with) spawned processes. Yet another use case is creating (essentially) a global grunt process that is meant to run in multiple directories. Spawning a grunt process will run grunt from cwd, but using grunt programmatically by requiring it from a different "repository" will use the one in that repositories node_modules directory. This is all just to point out that there _really are_ valid use cases for this.

Answer (score 14):

You can get inspiration on how to run grunt from code by looking at [grunt-cli](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli) which does this and which is a project maintained by the grunt folks.

Grunt is launched from code in [grunt-cli/bin/grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/f465a62c7d066a2b399101555c60a6f0eb3ff1b9/bin/grunt#L45) and you can read more about the options in [grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/77155e3f61d213c529a16ea595fc486fdeca28c9/lib/grunt/cli.js#L42-L104).

I use it in a private project like this:

```js
var grunt = require("grunt");
grunt.cli({
  gruntfile: __dirname + "/path/to/someGruntfile.js",
  extra: {key: "value"}
});
```

The key "extra" will be available from inside the gruntfile as `grunt.option("extra")`

Here is a bloggpost that describes an alternative way to run a grunt task: http://andrewduthie.com/2014/01/14/running-grunt-tasks-without-grunt-cli/

Comment: It is an interesting blogpost. Here is the updated link to it: http://andrewduthie.com/2014/01/14/running-grunt-tasks-without-grunt-cli