# Run Grunt tasks in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'd like to know how is possible to run in a node.js file a task for grunt.

I defined a task that works like that:

```
grunt backup --option1=sourceFolder --option2=destFolder
```

If I run it on CMD, all works fine.

But in the moment I try to run it in a node.js file, where there is an instruction like

```
var sourceFolder = __dirname + "\\" + process.argv[2];
var destFolder = __dirname + "\\"+ process.argv[3]; 

...other things...

exec("grunt backup --option1=" + sourceFolder + " --option2=" + destFolder);
```

happens this:

Running "copy:backup:grunt.option("option1"):grunt.option("option2")" (copy) task...

Why this happens? And there is a smater way in nodeJS instead of this ugly exec?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Grunt is not really well-designed to use it programatically. But it seems to be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564064/running-grunt-task-with-api-without-command-line So you could `require()` it and use the API.

Comment: you should really use `path.join(__dirname, process.argv[2])` instead of a string concat...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [GruntFile](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) with your defined tasks.  Then you simply run `grunt task-name` from the command line instead of running this within a separate node script.

Comment: Ok, I should, but if I need to launch tasks from a .js file? 
Exec or no way out?